# How can i switch AWS credentials easily in the terminal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a few different projects I work on. I use AWS and I use Kubernetes. I have a number of AWS credentials stored in my ~/.aws/credentials each with a label like

```
[account-1]
aws_access_key = x
aws_secret_access_key = y

[account-2]
aws_access_key = x
aws_secret_access_key = y
```

How can i toggle between them and easily set my config?
Currently I type `aws configure` in the terminal and manually paste the key/secret/regionn every time i want to switch between them.

Comment: AWS CLI takes --profile parameter where you can specify that. Also you can export porfile name as env variable.

Comment: You can use --profile on CLI to switch between profiles  see this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you hit the `aws configure` command, every time a new profile will be created in the `~/.aws/credentials`. You can generate all the required profiles single time and then set environment variable based on the project you're working.

For example,
while working on project 1, set the environment variable

```
export AWS_PROFILE=account-1
```

and while working on project 2, set the environment variable

```
export AWS_PROFILE=account-2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using zsh and [oh-my-zsh with the aws plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/aws/aws.plugin.zsh), you have the `asp` command.

```
asp account-1
```

and if your theme is set up nicely, your commandline prompt will tell you what account you're in.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Gunjan answer you can also pass the profile name like this

```
$ aws ecr get-login-password  --region us-east-1 --profile account-1
```

If you want to connect to multiple eks clusters

```
$ aws eks --region us-east-1  update-kubeconfig --name account-1-eks --region eu-west-1 --profile account-1
```

> You need to have proper IAM permissions to run this command

This command will generate a kube config file in `~/.kube`
move that file to some another location and add alias in your `bash_profile` or `.zshrc` like this line

```
account-1-eks='export KUBECONFIG=:/path/to/the/account-1-eks.config
```

Now reload your shell and you can switch using the alias like `account-1-eks`

You can repeat the steps for multiple accounts